# Add preparedStatement to select statement

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, jdbc

I have a select statement that I am using to gather the count of videos posted by users. I'm having it return userid upon having posted a certain number of videos. It works fine if I set it to a value, but I want to incorporate user input into it. So I created a Jfield for the user to enter a number into, but I'm unsure of how to add the prepared statement into it. When I try, I get an error of the sql statement near "?"

So my code without the prepared statement is

```
            try {

                Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdatabase", "root", "pass1234");
                        Statement stmt= con.createStatement();
                        String sql =" SELECT userid FROM video GROUP BY userid HAVING COUNT(video_name) = 2";



                        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            // handle row 

                        {


                             String i = rs.getString("userid");





                             model.addRow(new Object[]{i});
                                table.setModel(model);

                                }
                        }
                        {

                        con.close();}
                } catch(Exception e) {System.out.print (e);}



        }
```

And this is the preparedStatement I was trying to add, I was adding the '?' value into where I have the '2' currently.

```
String enter = txtEnter.getText();
                            PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                            prep.setString(1,enter);
```

Comment: You actually don't need a prepared statement for your current query.  What is wrong with your query?

Comment: You are trying to set String instead of setting Int.

Comment: I wanted to switch the '2' I have for HAVING COUNT(video_name) for a '?" and prompt the user for input. I get a "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1" error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't give the `sql` string on the `executeQuery()` call when you use `PreparedStatement`.

Use try-with-resources to ensure the JDBC resource are closed correctly.

Supply the SQL statement parameter as a number.

```java
int enter = Integer.parseInt(txtEnter.getText());
String sql = "SELECT userid" +
              " FROM video" +
             " GROUP BY userid" +
            " HAVING COUNT(video_name) = ?";
try (Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdatabase", "root", "pass1234");
     PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setInt(1, enter);
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            // handle row
            String userid = rs.getString("userid");
            model.addRow(new Object[]{i});
            table.setModel(model);
        }
    }
}
```